# Corporate Vagrant Cloud/Atlas

Tags: vagrant

I am wanting to setup an internal vagrant cloud/atlas location and was wondering if there is an official method? I have done a quick search and I am either not using the correct criteria or the official option is to use the Vagrant Cloud/Atlas.

Reasons for wanting an internal location:

- Performance during copies to local machine (We have some requirements
  for Windows as well as Linux)
- Privacy - Our corporate IT team do not like using any cloud
  offerings, yes, it is policy :(
- Complete control over the VM images
- I would like to have the users be able to use the shorthand names for
  simplification of use, EG: hashicorp/precise64 , or
  MyCorporateVMLocation/someOS/version

So far all I can see is (kinda) hacked options using nginx and a ubuntu [machine](https://medium.com/@jonursenbach/your-own-vagrant-cloud-f077625c6ac8#.3qsazt2h8)
I look forward to seeing what everyone else uses or compromises with!

Answer (score 0):

You can use another parameter from the [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) : `config.vm.box_url`

> `config.vm.box_url` - The URL that the configured box can be found at.
>   If config.vm.box is a shorthand to a box in HashiCorp's Atlas then
>   this value does not need to be specified. Otherwise, it should point
>   to the proper place where the box can be found if it is not installed.
>
> This can also be an array of multiple URLs. The URLs will be tried in
>   order. Note that any client certificates, insecure download settings,
>   and so on will apply to all URLs in this list.
>
> The URLs can also be local files by using the file:// scheme. For
>   example: "file:///tmp/test.box".

so if your IT provides a server as a repository for the box file, you can point the `config.vm.box_url` to this server

Comment: So the line to be added ( `config.vm.box_url` )are for the individual Vagrant box vagrant files? So once I have created the boxes, I then have to distribute these out the client machines?

Comment: yes once you create the box, each dev's Vagrantfile will have the line with the url and so they can download the boxes from a central repo

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, appreciated. Not a perfect solution, but a solution all the same.